# render json errors with a Ruby API : should I use an 'error' or a 'message' key?

Tags: json, ruby, api

i'm trying to create a Ruby API that will be called by a react app.

I'm not sure how I should render my errors.  In some tutorials, they use an *error* attribute, like

```
render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401
```

but sometimes they use *message* like

```
render json: { message: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401
```

Is there and what is the correct way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it only affects how you access the JSON hash (or 'object' in JavaScript) on your frontend, ie through the "error" key or the "message" key.

Typically `message` should be used for information, and `error` should be used for things that go wrong. There is no clear convention as you noted, but in the case of `400` statuses, `error` may be more appropriate, whereas in say `300` statuses, `message` may make more sense.